# Can you use Pascal's Triangle to easily find independent event probability sums, so long as the summed probabilities are equal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been doing some algebra to see what happens when you sum independent event probabilities together (or whatever the union operator is called) and found that

> Given $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=P(D)=P(E)=c$
>
> $P(A\cup B)=2c-c^2$
>
> $P(A\cup B\cup C)=3c-3c^2-c^3$
>
> $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)=4c-6c^2-4c^3-c^4$
>
> $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E)=5c-10c^2-10c^3-5c^4-c^5$

Now, notwithstanding my math being wrong, notice the pattern of numbers in the polynomials

> (1) 2 1
>
> (1) 3 3 1
>
> (1) 4 6 4 1
>
> (1) 5 10 10 5 1

That's Pascal's Triangle, right there. Is this a thing? Does it diverge as the number grows larger? Is the following a thing

> Given $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=P(D)=P(E)=P(F)=P(G)=c$
>
> $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D\cup E\cup F\cup G)=7c-21c^2-35c^3-35c^4-21c^5-7c^6-c^7$

Is this a thing? Does it have a name? Can I use this to easily find sums like this in the future?

Just stumbled upon this. Feels so out of no where? Is it correct? Or is my math wrong?

Comment: This is called inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I look it up on wiki. Didn't see a mention of Pascal's Triangle and is in general worded in a way I can barely read. Care to explain, I've super curious! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ Inclusion-Exclusion principle in finding probability of the union of finitely many events.

It says that if $A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_n$ are finitely many events then

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i) -\sum_{i<j}\mathbb{P}(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum_{i<j<k}\mathbb{P}(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)- \cdots +(-1)^{n-1} \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right).$$